# Autocomplete places search not working

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQ7XPD_fZf8YCv-1gEE_Yid3xzFaEy7DU&libraries=places" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

      var input = document.getElementById('searchbox');
      var options = {
       bounds: defaultBounds,
       types: ['establishment']
    };

     autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
</script>

<div class="col-md-6">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="PickUp">Pick Up location</label>
    <input type="text" id="searchbox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
```

When I type something in the textbox, nothing happens. What's wrong with this code? The code above is refering the code from the google web developer site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `&callback=init` in the script src url. and put all script code inside `function init(){...}`

```js
function init() {
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

  var input = document.getElementById('searchbox');
  var options = {
    bounds: defaultBounds,
    types: ['establishment']
  };

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQ7XPD_fZf8YCv-1gEE_Yid3xzFaEy7DU&libraries=places&callback=init" async defer></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="PickUp">Pick Up location</label>
      <input type="text" id="searchbox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, can I use the same API key for my website google map and autocomplete search or I needed a second key? @Deep 3015

Comment: I use the same key for google map and autocomplete yet either one of them is not functioning, what could be the problem?

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/7z7sbnt4/ where both are working with one key